# Share a kotlin source file between a java6 kotlin project and a java8 kotlin project

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I have a Kotlin project that needs to work with Java6 and another that needs to work with Java8. How can I share a kotlin source file that contains common definitions between both the projects?

```
KotlinProjectA(jvmTarget="1.6") <-- [common.kt] --> KotlinProjectB(jvmTarget="1.8")
```

Comment: The easiest solution is to compile both projects as jvmTarget=1.6. This is fully forward-compatible and won't have any downsides.

Comment: The project that currently has jvmTarget=1.8 has dependencies on other libraries that work only with Java8. It also uses Date/Time and regex features that are only available in Java8. So it cannot be compiled with jvmTarget=1.6

Comment: Which build system are you using for your projects?

Comment: gradle (plain groovy, not Kotlin DSL)

Comment: Then simply create a separate module with jvmTarget=1.6 and put your common.kt there.

Comment: can this module with jvmTarget=1.6 then be specified as a dependency for the jvmTarget=1.8 module? Is that an acceptable thing to do, given that they have different bytecode versions?

Comment: Yes, of course it can be specified as a dependency. Bytecode versions are backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [yole's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147024/yole) suggestion - created a separate module with jvmTarget=1.6; both the jvm 1.6 and 1.8 projects were able to use this common dependency. The jvm1.8 project had no issues with the dependency with Java6 bytecode.